# GET request slow in Scrolling events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, chromium

I have a react project with some code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
};

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
};

handleScroll(event) {
    this.load();
};

load() {
    console.log('Loading');
    $.get('/latest-dishes?page=1&items=6', function(data) {
        console.log('Loaded');
        console.log(data);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={e => this.load()}>Load</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I run the server on local. When I click the button, data is loaded immediately.

But, when I scroll "one unit", data is slower loaded.

I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7.

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE 1**

I've test this project, It works well on Firefox, this issue occurs on Chrome.

**UPDATE 2**

This issue occurs on Chrome 56. It works well on Chromium 58

Comment: What is the usage of attaching `load()` function to `scroll` event of `window`? With every scroll, you are fetching hundred of times your data...

Comment: I scroll only "One unit". It seems to be a bug of chrome 56.

Comment: What does the console prints ? Does the console logs `Loading` immediately, when you scroll "one unit"?

Comment: ```Loading``` shows imediately, but ```Loaded``` shows slower than a postman request. I've tested on chrome 57, 58, It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use component will mount instead of component did mount because component did mount triggers after initial state and render whereas component will mount will trigger before render

```
componentWillMount() {
window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);};
```

Read this for more preferance :)

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: This issue occurs on chrome only, Firefox works well,

Comment: since lots of data is fetched on your scroll.. it is talking more time to fetch it.. and you are passing a refrence to a function which is passing reference to another function which does not make any sense

Comment: I've tested on Chome 57, 58, Firefox, It works well. This issue occurs on Chrome 56.

Comment: Possible .. React is a new technology so it might not run on older versions of chrome which were there before react.

Comment: Maybe, But I think chrome 56 currently is stable release version.